# try catch быстрее чем @ ?

Tags: php

```
try {
include('');
} catch(e) {
 die('error');
}
```

или

```
@include('') or die('error');
```

или

```
if (file_exists('')) {
 include('');
}
```

или

```
$result = ('SELECT 1 FROM files WHERE file_name="" LIMIT 1');
if ($result) {
 include('');
}
```

Comment: Хорошие вопросы нужно поощрять!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Правильнее.
Собака не избавляет от ошибки, она лишь подавляет ее вывод

А try-catch позволяет не только подавить, но и еще принять какие-то конкретные меры.
по скорости - очень забавно. Если все идет гладко, это самый быстрый способ, за исключением просто голого кода. При возникновении ошибки - один из самых медленных.

```
<?php
$time = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++){
    @divByZero($i,0);
}
print((microtime(true)-$time).'<br />');
//1.66923713684 - делим на 0
//1.25963785172 - делим на 3

$time = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++){
    try{
        divByZeroE($i,0);
    }catch(Exception $e){

    }
}
print((microtime(true)-$time).'<br />');
//5.61499404907 - делим на 0
//0.690489969254 - делим на 3

$time = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++){
    divByZeroIfOnly($i,0);
}
print((microtime(true)-$time).'<br />');
//0.69531083107 - делим на 0
//0.69578036312 - делим на 3

function divByZero($a,$b){
    return $a/$b;
}

function divByZeroE($a,$b){
    if($b==0)
        throw new Exception('Division By Zero');
    return $a/$b;
}

function divByZeroIfOnly($a,$b){
    if($b==0)
        return false;
    return $a/$b;
}
```

теперь полный? =)

Comment: Хорошие ответы тоже)

Comment: Тут не хабр чтобы вместо ответов писать целые статьи!

Comment: Вот вам результаты сложнейших тестов, непосильных простым смертным, уважаемый @good15